# como evitar EOL em python

Tags: python

Tenho este código:

```
número = 4
chute = input('quanto é 2+2?:\')

if chute == número:
    print('parabéns, vc acertou :)')
else:
    print('ops, parece que você errou, tente novamente que você vai conseguir acertar. Você consegue :)')
```

E fica aparecendo isso:

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Como corrigir?

Answer (score 1):

O erro é porq vc está escapando o caractere de aspas simples no final da função `input`

Tente isso: `chute = input('quanto é 2+2?:')`

Além disso, o python tem características diferentes das outras linguagem tais como a indentação e o uso de `:` ao final dos comandos.

Outra coisa é que vc vai estar comparando um `int` com uma `str` visto o que função `input()` retorna.

Tente isso: `chute = int(input('quanto é 2+2?:'))`

O python não reclama sobre acento em variáveis, porém não é o mais indicado.

---

```
número = 4
chute = int(input('quanto é 2+2?:'))

if chute == número:
    print('parabéns, vc acertou :)')
else:
    print('ops, parece que você errou, tente novamente que você vai conseguir acertar. Você consegue :)')
```

[image: print]

Comment: fiz isso ai, e ainda tá dando o msm erro

Comment: editei a resposta com o código alterado e um print funcional pra ver se te ajuda!

Comment: Pergunta, o int significa oq? É q eu to aprendendo usando uma apostila q eu baixei da internet

Comment: `int()` é uma função que converte o parâmetro passado pro tipo inteiro. Ex: `"4"` é uma string, por estar entre aspas, que com o `int("4")` vira `4` que é um número

Comment: Talvez aprender com alguém ensinando seja melhor! Recomendo os vídeos do `Curso em Vídeo` do Gustavo Guanabara

Comment: valeu pela dica, tamo junto cara é nóis :)

Comment: refiz o código do zero e agora vai dar erro: unexpected ident

Comment: qual IDE vc está usando? geralmente ela aponta a linha do erro. Esse parece que vc indentou de maneira errada alguma parte do código

Comment: to usando IDE 3.9.2. Mais consegui resolver o erro mais agora n tá mostrando a resposta q eu quero

Comment: agr o problema deve estar na comparação, no `if`

Comment: @KingTrollex se te ajudei, marque a resposta como certa por favor :D

Comment: eu n to conseguindo resolver esse problema

Comment: como que ficou o código?

Comment: eu n to conseguindo progredir com o erro: unexpected ident. Já escrevi e reescrivi o código várias vezes e eu to parado no mesmo lugar

Comment: Você tem que dar exatos 4 espaços ou apertar tab 1 vez

Comment: valeu pela dica

Comment: fiz o que o vc disse e continua a ocorrendo o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 0):

**EOL while scanning string literal**

Ocorre quando alguma das *quotes*('', "", """""") é aberta e não fechada devidamente.

E.g

TESTE OS EXEMPLOS ABAIXO NO PROMPT DO PYTHON

*AMBIENTE DO IDLE QUE CONTÉM TRÊS **ANGLE BRACKETS*** (**>>>**)

Se testar os exemplos abaixo todos resultarão em erros **EOL**.

```
>>> 'Seu texto vai aqui
>>> 'Seu texto vai aqui"
>>> "Seu texto vai aqui"""
```

Se aspas simples foi aberta, a mesma deve ser fechada. Vale ressaltar que
as aspas são diferentes umas das outras.

'' -> aspas simples

"" -> aspas duplas

"""""" -> aspas triplas

Se abrir simples, apenas aspas simples pode fechar aspas simples. E assim por diante.

E no seu caso, um "escape character" foi utilizado de maneira incorreta que é essa barra invertida com a aspa simples `(\')`, fazendo com que o interpretador do Python entenda que a sua aspa simples no final seja considerada uma aspa literal, ou seja, parte do texto, ao invés de uma **quote** ou um delimitador de textos do Python. Para resolver, adicione mais uma aspa simples `(\'')` ou remova a barra invertida `(')`.

p.s Para evitar EOL matenha a simetria das aspas.